# What db should i use in HTML5 game development to be able easily convert it into android webview game?

Tags: android, database, html, webview, 2d-games

I can't find a good answer to this question.

I want to create an HTML5 game with phaser framework and convert it into Android/iOS app (webview).

The game suppose to work a lot with database (update, select)

Do any one can suggest me the right way to work to be able after that to convert it with minimal time wasting?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to use a database to store local data on the device, or a database where your server side/webservice gets data from?

Comment: @SpeedyCodezales i prefer to store the data on the device.